# Material-ui MuiThemeProvider Not applying

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to customize the theme of my app, however the default theme color is still showing instead of the one i try to achieve

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import MuiThemeProvider from "@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import createMuiTheme from "@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme";

// components
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

// pages
import home from "./pages/home";
import login from "./pages/login";
import signup from "./pages/signup";
```

here is my attemp to customize the theme.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  pallete: {
    primary: {
      light: "#67daff",
      main: "#03a9f4",
      dark: "#007ac1",
      contrastText: "#fff",
    },
    secondary: {
      light: "#7953d2",
      main: "#4527a0",
      dark: "#000070",
      contrastText: "#fff",
    },
  },
});
```

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className="App">
          <Router>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="container">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={login} />
                <Route exact path="/signup" component={signup} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8wIn.png)

[The one i tried to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOtBJ.png)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// Material UI Stuff
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";


class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar className="nav-container">
          <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to="/login">
            Login
          </Button>
          <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to="/">
            Home
          </Button>
          <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to="/signup">
            Signup
          </Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

there, i want the pallete to be applied in the navbar, however it wont applied. i'm just following some tutorial so i don't really know where the error is.

Comment: I don't see any example where you show using any material ui components. Could you attach it ?

Comment: done mate, i have just post the navbar code i tried to applid the pallete. thanks!

Comment: word pallete incorrect -> palette

Comment: https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/

Comment: thanks mate!! Oh, how come i didn't saw it :D

Answer (score 0):

you can define color in style format. if you want to change of the color of the container class, you can type;

```
 class App extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <div className="App">
       <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container" style={{
            color: "black",
            backgroundColor: "white",
          }} >
          ...
```